# Android: EditText in ScrollView goes of the screen when kayboard appears

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I am trying to create a login screen. I have used ScrollView to hold input fields. I have following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout ... >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_menu" ... >
        <ImageButton ... />
        <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView... />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_menu"
        android:overScrollMode="always">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.edittext.EditText
                android:id="@+id/user_name_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/input_height_size"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_strock"
                android:hint="@string/user_Name_Email_EditText"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textColorHint="@color/White"
                android:textSize="@dimen/register_input_text_size"
                pixlui:typeface="MuseoSans.otf"/>

            <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.edittext.EditText.... />
            <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.button.Button... />
            <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView... />
            <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView... />
            <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.textview.TextView... />
            <com.neopixl.pixlui.components.button.Button... />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can see full xml [here](http://pastebin.com/WcLS7EwR).
When I click on EditText user_name_email, it goes off the screen.

Before click:

[image: Before click]

After click:

[image: After click]

I have tried `scrollTo(x, y)` and `smootScrollTo(x, y)` bu they didn't work.

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

`adjustPan` works but I want it to work with `adjustResize`.
Is it possible?

Comment: Add this property : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" to <activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Any specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following line in the manifest file, for the activity you need the change.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Use it as shown below:

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:label="title_for_activity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add this to manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in the targeted activity tag.